# End Accents in Other Cultures

Tags: musicology, meter, accent, world-music

**Disclaimer:** It's difficult mixing terminology between Western and non-Western musics, but I'll try to make my question as clear as possible.

Western Classical music most often has an accent at the start of a given metrical unit; we call it the downbeat. Although there may be an anacrusis, the metrical accent nevertheless typically aligns with the beginning of a barline. In contrast, I've heard that some non-Western cultures are "end accented" and focus on the ends of units/phrases; is this in fact the case?

And a bonus question, if this even exists: are there cultures that metrically emphasize something *other* than the beginning or end?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to the usage of 'phrase' and 'unit' here, and the way they seem to be used interchangeably. by 'unit' do you mean something similar to what would normally be called a 'bar'?

Comment: As an illustration of my confusion : *Imagine a string of 16 sixteenth notes. In Western music, the metrical accent will be on the first sixteenth note to mark the beginning of the unit* - even with really 'straight' accentation (say, in 4/4), that would only be the case if the first note fell on (say) the first beat of the bar.

Comment: By "unit" I just mean some upper level of hierarchy equal or greater than what we would normally call a "bar." The reason I switch terms around is just because I don't know enough about gamelan music to know what to call it!

Comment: I'm just thinking if modelled in Western terms, and assuming (say) straight 4/4 accenting, you'd normally assume that if you had 15 weak notes followed by a strong note, that you'd think of the strong note *as* the bar boundary. So I'm wondering why it can't be seen as the beginning of a 'unit' in Gamelan music, even if it's the end of a phrase. I realise this may be showing my own ignorance of Gamelan.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really a strict dichotomy, Richard. We have a _notational convention_ of placing strong beats immediately after the bar line, but strong beats at the beginning of a phrase are only _one_ of the rhythmic possibilities available. Phrases that start with an anacrusis, even 15/16 worth of anacrusis, are not uncommon, and phrases that end on a strong beat are as common as dirt, especially at section and movement ends.

Comment: @Richard, I'm not familiar with Gamelan music, but to help me better understand, is this an accurate rewording of your Q: "whereas Western music places metrical accents immediately after a bar line, Gamelan music places these accents immediately before a bar line. Are there other cultural traditions that do this?" I assume Gamelan music is written with measures / in meter--I personally wouldn't know how to apply the concept of metrical accents to a musical tradition that doesn't use meters. I would probably get stuck trying to distinguish metrical accents from other accents in the music.

Comment: @jdjazz Gamelan music doesn't really have barlines, but it's a good way of rewording the question, and I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: I assume this question isn't looking for "genres that habitually accent some part of the 'bar' other than the 'downbeat,'" because there are a lot of those: mazurka, reggae, the backbeat mentioned in the answer. I guess you're looking for a different kind of organization, a "back-to-front" thinking. Hm. One of the difficulties with questions like these is that they might ask us to "prove a negative": If somebody can offer one example that satisfies, great, but until then we can't prove it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

Rock, pop, and rhythm and blues often emphasize the second and last beat. This emphasis also serves as a backdrop to funk (more below). Reggae has an even heavier emphasis on the same beats often accompanied with an offbeat emphasis.

Regarding the bonus question, jazz emphasizes the offbeat and in the jazz "subculture" the band leader typically counts in by snapping the fingers of one hand on the offbeat. In contrast, [funk emphasizes the first beat together with "in the pocket"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHE6hZU72A4&feature=youtu.be&t=9s) usually expressed as a few select notes from a shuffle pattern while leaving out (some) dotted notes. It might be a stretch to say that these examples belong to a specific culture, but all these genres are ultimately of African-American origin.

What these examples have in common is often multiple layers of emphases from different instruments. In this regard, these modern genres are rather **polyrhytmic** than **homorhythmic**. In postclassical contemporary art music, polyrhytms take this concept to the extreme. They are most common in minimalistic (or more specifically "postminimalistic") works, which originated mainly in New York during the 1960s.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently studied *solkattu*, South-Indian (Carnatic) spoken percussion, which could be viewed as one instance of this ending accent.

One element of *solkattu* is *gopucha*, which translates to "cow's tail." *Gopucha* is a process by which rhythmic elements become increasingly tightened together. Because of this tightening, it's not always immediately clear when the rhythmic process will end.

Here is a quick example of *gopucha*; listen to how the performer's "ta di gi na" syllables become increasingly closer together.

Another major element of this style is *kanakku*, which translates to "calculation." When a *gopucha* is to be introduced, then, the performer must *calculate* when to begin the *gopucha* so that the ending aligns with the conclusion of the *tala* (meter).

As such, the practice can be understood as "end accented" because it's not about processes starting together (as is so often the case in the Western style), but rather processes *ending* together.

(In the 6.5 years since asking this question, I have not found any styles with accents in the middles of units.)

Comment: Even then, I'd hesitate to bring the word "accent" into the discussion. My knowledge of tala is pretty basic, and this seems to be a pretty complex tala, but they still mark it with hand gestures of "palm down vs palm up" (I'm also used to "palm down, followed by counting on fingers"). I've followed simpler talas that were comparable to 4/4—a "downbeat" followed by three "other beats." So even if the rhythmic pattern of this video focuses on "the end," there's still "a beginning." Plus, although, yes, there's a distinct musical emphasis on an "offbeat," the tala is undisturbed; if anything,...

Comment: ... it helps illustrate the idea that conceptual metric "emphases" do not have to correlate to actual performative ones.